# Migrate attributes from old line feature to a new one where differences in geometry and common attribute exist between the two

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I recently received an older Centerline modified by an external consulting firm my management team hired (which they contracted out GIS work for without consulting their own GIS staff, go figure.)

As a result, they used old open data which while visually similar in most cases, the geometry isn't identical. [image: Geometry differences]

Also, my new Centerline has around 6kish more segments and a quick check throughout also tells me that a significant number of those were digitized differently. Example: Old Centerline = One segment VS New Centerline = three segments for the same spot.

As I have several thousand segments where the common attribute doesn't match for an easy join, and not exact geometry in all places, I'm a bit in "analysis paralysis" on how to plan the best way to tackle this, and in what order of steps.

Comment: Well, conflating the records yourself is one avenue, but so is demanding that the contractor do the job right.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't consider that. Will report back on my tests. I see that I can fix the geometry here plus attempt to match the segmentation with conflation. How would you recommend addressing the common attribute value discrepancy after this? As per the contractor situation, speaking more on that would get this post removed.

Comment: Instead of moving attributes from your old to the new shapes, you might try to match a copy of your old layer with attributes to the new shapes.  The snapping tool has some options you might try.  You might run a dissolve on the new layer prior to the snapping.

Comment: @johns For your method to work, are there any specific conditions to account for? I know for a fact that there are some physical road changes reflected in the new centerline vs the old one (Additions from new development + existing revitalizations) etc.

Comment: I'd check if end points of dissolved new are close to old.. if this is a case,  run Near between dissolved midpoint and old lines. This will give you enough for attribute join. If you old are not intersect each other at their ends, ask boss for premium pay rate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a (small) buffer around one of the lines.
2. Join the attributes from the buffer to the other line if it intersects with the buffer. Best don't overwrite existing attributes, create a copy for it to be able to compare the values for each segment.
3. If the second line intersect the buffer of more then one of the first line, get the attribute from the buffer with the largest intersection.